# Azure Eventhub / Event Processor Host: Partitioning not working as predicted

Tags: azure, partitioning, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

We are working on a project right now which implements and uses the Azure Eventhub.
We use the Event Processor Host to process the data from the Eventhub. We have 32 partitions distributed on to 3 nodes and are wondering how the Event Processor Host distributes and balances the partitions on to the receivers / nodes – especially when using partition key.

[image: All data from all 4 customers]

We currently have 4 different customers (blue, orange, purple and light blue) which sends us different sizes of data. As you can see the blue customer on the left sends approx. 132k strings of data, while the light blue customer on the right only sends 28.
Our theory was, that given a partitionkey based on the customer (the coloridentification) we would see that a customers data would only be placed in one node.
Instead we can see that the data is somehow evenly distributed on the 3 nodes as seen below:

Node 1:

[image: Node 1]

Node 2:

[image: Node 2]

Node 3:

[image: Node 3]

Is there something we’ve misunderstood in regards to how the use of the partitionkey works? From what we’ve read in the documentation, then when we don’t specify partition keys, then a “round-robin” approach will be used – but even with the use of a partition key, it somehow distributes them evenly.
Are we somehow stressing the nodes – with a blue customer having a huge amount of data and another customer having almost nothing? Or what is going on?

To visualize our theory we've drawn the following:
[image: Possibly what is happening]

So are we stressing the top node with a blue customer, that in the end has to move a partition to the middle node?

Comment: What do you mean with a node? A process running an Event Processor Host ?

Comment: You might be mixing up two things here: Event Hub Processors use Azure Blob storage leases to assign and distribute partitions between different processor instances (what you call Node I assume). The partition key has nothing to do in that side whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partition key is intended to be used when you want to be sure that a set of events is routed to the same partition, but you don't want to assign an explicit partition.  In short, use of a partition key is an explicit request to control routing and prevents the service from balancing across partitions.

When you specify a partition key, it is used to produce a hash value that the Event Hubs service uses to assign the partition to which the event will be routed.   Every event that uses the same partition key will be published to the same partition.

To allow the service to round-robin when publishing, you cannot specify a partition key or an explicit partition identifier.

Comment: so isn't that what I am trying to do, and which is not happening? I added a partitionkey based on the CustomerId, which I presume means that all data belonging to CustomerId_blue should go one route and all data belonging to CustomerId_green to another. Instead some blues goes one route, some another and I end up having a mix up 3 different CustomerId's on each route. Or am I misunderstanding something? Isn't that what round-robin means/does - evenly balances the data, not caring about if it is CustomerId_blue or _green?

Comment: Serkant has already offered thoughts on the general scenario, so I'll avoid repeating that guidance.   

What I do want to mention is that I believe your core assumption of "using a partition key will help ensure that events are spread evenly among partitions" isn't necessarily a valid assumption.   The guarantee is only that "events with the same key will go to the same partition" - it is a valid scenario to have your four partition keys end up being routed to the same partition, albeit unlikely.

Comment: It's a bit hard to comment further on the "route" and "node" that you're speaking of, as they're not Event Hubs concepts and I'm not clear on exactly what you mean by the terms. 

It seems as if you may be saying that you see events using the **exact same** partition key being routed to different partitions, which should not be the case.    If that is what you're seeing, it would be helpful to see the code that you're using to send events.

Answer (score 1):

Jesse already explained what partition key is good for so I won't repeat that.

If you want customer to consumer-node affinity, you should consider dedicating an independent eventhub to each customer so that you can tell your system something like

1. node-1 processes data from customerA only by consuming events from eventhub-1
2. node-2 processes data from customerB only by consuming events from eventhub-2
    and so on...

Making use of partition key doesn't really address you business logic here.

One more thing. If you are planning to run this with larger number of customers in the future then you also need to consider to scale out your design to create affinity between customer and EH namespace as well.

Comment: Ah okay - so I should actually create an eventhub for each customer? That sounds like a lot of work when considering having a lot of customers (and not only 4). The reason for placing all data for each customer the same place/node is that when I need to fetch it from the nodes, I don't need to call 2-3 nodes, but only 1 and that will eventually optimize my perfomance / executiontime.